# How to find the XY coordinates of a VBox within an Anchorpane in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, coordinates

I am struggling with finding the XY coords of the top-left corner of a VBox that is added to an Anchorpane. I have read many posts about Bounds, local, layout and parent and boy is it confusing!

I have a drag-drop functionality in my app, so all i want is to get the XY of the VBox when it is dropped inside the Anchorpane.

Is there a straight-forward way of doing this?

I am assuming that the coords will be relevant to the parent node, in this case the Anchorpane. Is that the right way?

Many Thanks
Ash

Comment: I think you're going to need a full example. It looks like you can use [getBoundsInParent](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getBoundsInParent()) but there could be some confusion before and after the object is dropped.

Comment: I also think a [mre] here would be beneficial. It's not clear what's being dragged-and-dropped or what the purpose of getting the XY coordinates of the `VBox` is.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I wanted to include a minimal reproductible example, but that might be quite large and would take time to refactor it into a smaller code base. The thing is, I need help understanding layout, local and parent bounds, how to use them to get real coordinates of a child of Node on my view. What is the simplest way to explain these Bounds methods?

Comment: Local bounds are just that, the bounds of the `Node` itself in its own coordinate space. Parent bounds are the bounds of a `Node` within its _parent's_ coordinate space. They can be, and often are, different. The parent bounds take into account any layout and transforms applied to the `Node`, whereas the local bounds do not. Note you can convert these (and any arbitrary) bounds to different coordinate spaces (e.g. with `localToParent`, `localToScene`, `screenToLocal`, etc.). So it depends in which coordinate space you want the "real" XY coordinates for and how exactly your UI is structured.

Comment: Also, use @Slaw if you want me to be aware of a reply.